# add custom function to Codeigniter config such as site_url() & base_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter

we need to have a new function such as base_url() , named main_site_url() to being able to use it exactly as the same as site_url().

I've just added this to main config file in application/config:

```
$config['main_site_url'] = 'http//iksna.com/';
```

and this code to /system/core/config.php

```
/**
 * Main Site URL
 * Returns main_site_url . index_page [. uri_string]
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the URI string
 * @return  string
 */
function main_site_url($uri = '')
{
    if ($uri == '')
    {
        return $this->slash_item('main_site_url').$this->item('index_page');
    }

    if ($this->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
    {
        $suffix = ($this->item('url_suffix') == FALSE) ? '' : $this->item('url_suffix');
        return $this->slash_item('main_site_url').$this->slash_item('index_page').$this->_uri_string($uri).$suffix;
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->slash_item('main_site_url').$this->item('index_page').'?'.$this->_uri_string($uri);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------
```

but now, it is not accessible by: `main_site_url();`

is it accessible by: `$this->config->main_site_url()`;

i have this error when is use `main_site_url()`;

error:

```
Call to undefined function main_site_url()
```

Comment: it is better to you write in it constant file

Comment: better to use custom variable like $config['main_site_url'] = 'your url'; and access it like $this->config->item('main_site_url'); anywhere in site.

Comment: Make custom helper with function `main_site_url()` that's returning `site_url()` and autoload it.

Comment: because this is just one function i agree with @Tpojka - make it a helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own by the following way:

**Step 1:**

In you `application/config/config.php` add this, `$config['main_site_url'] = 'http//iksna.com/';`

**Step 2:**

In `system/core/Config.php` add a new function `main_site_url()` like `base_url()`, `site_url()` which are already defined there:

```
public function main_site_url($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
{
    $main_site_url = $this->slash_item('main_site_url');

    if (isset($protocol))
    {
        if ($protocol === '')
        {
            $main_site_url = substr($main_site_url, strpos($main_site_url, '//'));
        }
        else
        {
            $main_site_url = $protocol.substr($main_site_url, strpos($main_site_url, '://'));
        }
    }
    return $main_site_url.ltrim($this->_uri_string($uri), '/');
}
```

Step 3:

Now add the following code in `system/helpers/url_helper.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists('main_site_url'))
{
    function main_site_url($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
    {
        return get_instance()->config->main_site_url($uri, $protocol);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `main_site_url()` anywhere in your controllers, libraries and views just like `base_url()`, `site_url()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
/system/application/libraries
```

Create one file named

```
custom_function.php
```

add function main_site_url inside custom_function.php

call function in controller file using

```
$this->custom_function->main_site_url();
```